# Can Google Cloud HSM host KEK's for local Oracle databases TDE?

Tags: oracle, encryption, tde, google-cloud-kms

We are currently looking for a setup to implement Transparent Data Encyption on Oracle databases.
We are looking for Cloud HSM solutions. Can Google Cloud HSM interface with local Oracle databases for TDE encryption?

Thanks!

Olivier

Comment: Can you add more tags

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Cloud side, we don't provide native support for our Cloud HSM with Oracle's TDE.  I believe one of the requirements is that a PKCS#11 interface is needed and that's not supported by Cloud HSM at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Oliver, Oracle TDE does not support 3rd party HSMs (on-prem or in any cloud) for key management; for your use case, an Oracle Key Vault 21 cluster installed on-prem (or, with proper networking, in your OCI tenancy from the Oracle Cloud Marketplace (https://cloudmarketplace.oracle.com/marketplace/app/OracleKeyVault)) would be a fully supported option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).